# How to draw dashed line with finger in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics

I need to draw a line with dashes at regular gaps by sliding finger on the iPhone screen. I have written the following code for that and it is drawing the dashed line but the gaps are not regular and thus it is not looking good. I have also provided a link to the video showing the issue Please help!

Link to video:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/56721867/Screen%20Recording%207.mov

```
   CGPoint mid1 = midPoint__5(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
   CGPoint mid2 = midPoint__5(currentPoint, previousPoint1);
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   [self.layer renderInContext:context];
   self.lineColor=[arrObj objectAtIndex:colorTag];
   CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
   CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
   CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);//use for making circle ,rect or line effect===============
   CGFloat dashArray[] = {2,8,2,8};
   CGContextSetLineDash(context,2,dashArray, 4);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
   self.lineColor=[arrObj objectAtIndex:[AppHelper userDefaultsForKey:@"ColorTag"].intValue];//color tag on button click
   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
   CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1.0);
   CGBlendMode blendStyle=isErase?kCGBlendModeClear:kCGBlendModeNormal; 
   CGContextSetBlendMode(context,blendStyle);
   CGContextStrokePath(context);
   [super drawRect:rect];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rather unclear from the code, but based on the video and a hunch I'd guess a single swipe with the finger ends up as several line segments. This means that the dashing starts from scratch several times, creating the effect in the video. You probably need a NSMutableArray where you put all those currentPoint into, and then draw them all as one line every time you redraw.

This question has more information on how to draw lines in this way: [iPhone Core Graphics thicker dashed line for subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229871/iphone-core-graphics-thicker-dashed-line-for-subview)

Comment: I would agree with this guess. In your drawRect, you should have a loop that goes through all points, and does a CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint for each point, and then a single CGContextStrokePath.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do what you are trying, it uses Quartz instead of CoreGraphics. You can use either Quartz or CoreGraphics.

```
//
//  TestView.h
// 
//
//  Created by Syed Arsalan Pervez on 2/18/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 SAPLogix. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestView : UIView
{
    NSMutableArray *_points;
}

@end


//
//  TestView.m
// 
//
//  Created by Syed Arsalan Pervez on 2/18/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 SAPLogix. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TestView.h"

@interface UserPoint : NSObject
{
    BOOL _start;
    BOOL _end;
    CGPoint _point;
}

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL start;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL end;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGPoint point;

@end

@implementation UserPoint

@end

@implementation TestView

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _points = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UserPoint *)addPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    UserPoint *_userPoint = [UserPoint new];
    _userPoint.point = point;
    [_points addObject:_userPoint];
    [_userPoint release];

    return [_points lastObject];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UserPoint *_userPoint = [self addPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
    _userPoint.start = YES;
    _userPoint = nil;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UserPoint *_userPoint = [self addPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
    _userPoint = nil;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UserPoint *_userPoint = [self addPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
    _userPoint.end = YES;
    _userPoint = nil;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path setLineWidth:15];
    CGFloat dash[] = {15,20};
    [path setLineDash:dash count:2 phase:0];
    [path setLineCapStyle:kCGLineCapRound];
    CGPoint lastPoint;
    for (UserPoint *_point in _points)
    {
        if (_point.start || _point.end)
            [path moveToPoint:_point.point];
        else
        {
            [path addQuadCurveToPoint:_point.point controlPoint:lastPoint];
        }
        lastPoint = _point.point;
    }
    [path stroke];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_points release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Adding quad curve requires a complex calculation so please use it wisely and optimize it.

Comment: Thanks for the code and it is working but how will I erase the drawing?

Comment: @Developer You can do it in several ways it depends how do you want to do it. One way is by detecting touch and removing the points that were intersected and setting the previous point of the one that was intersected as end = YES and the next one as start = YES.

Comment: How can I find the intersecting points? Can you please provide sample code for this? Its really urgent! Thanks!